# Python/P2P - Unable to connect to rendezvous server

Tags: python, port, nodes, p2p, blockchain

I am trying to create a `P2P` node using python (`pyp2p`) but I am getting this error:

```
Eamons-MacBook-Pro:blockchain eamonwhite$ python3 serveralice.py
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eamonwhite/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyp2p/net.py", line 732, in start
    rendezvous_con = self.rendezvous.server_connect()
  File "/Users/eamonwhite/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyp2p/rendezvous_client.py", line 92, in server_connect
    con.connect(server["addr"], server["port"])
  File "/Users/eamonwhite/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyp2p/sock.py", line 189, in connect
    self.s.bind((src_ip, 0))
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not NoneType

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serveralice.py", line 10, in <module>
    alice.start()
  File "/Users/eamonwhite/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyp2p/net.py", line 735, in start
    raise Exception("Unable to connect to rendezvous server.")
Exception: Unable to connect to rendezvous server.
```

---

My relevant code looks like this:

```
from uuid import uuid4
from blockchain import Blockchain
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from pyp2p.net import *
import time

#Setup Alice's p2p node.
alice = Net(passive_bind="192.168.1.131", passive_port=44444, interface="en0", node_type="passive", debug=1)
alice.start()
alice.bootstrap()
alice.advertise()

while 1:
    for con in alice:
        for reply in con:
            print(reply)

    time.sleep(1)

...
```

It is getting stuck on the `Net` function right at the beginning - something to do with the `rendezvous` package. The IP is my IP on the my network, and I port forwarded 44444 although I'm not sure if I need to do that or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I am new to this, apparently with the way the server code was configured, it needed a rendezvous server to work (a node that handles all the other nodes). It is in `net.py` of the `pyp2p` package:

```
# Bootstrapping + TCP hole punching server.
rendezvous_servers = [
    {
        "addr": "162.243.213.95",
        "port": 8000
    }
]
```

The address was the problem, obviously it is just a placeholder IP. So then I realized I needed my own rendezvous server, and I used this code - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StorjOld/pyp2p/master/pyp2p/rendezvous_server.py.

However I had to debug this file a little, it ended up needing to have `import sys`, `import time` and `import re` statements at the top before it would work. Now I am going to host it on my raspberry pi so that it is always up to handle nodes :)